# $f(x) = \ln(xe^x)$. Find all $a >$ 0 such that two functions $f′(x)$ and $1 − f′′(x)$ with [2] domain $(a, ∞)$ have the same range.

Tags: exponential-function

f(x) = ln(xe^x). Find all a > 0 such that two functions f′(x) and 1 − f′′(x) with [2] domain (a, ∞) have the same range.

ln(xe^x) = lnx + le^x
lne=1; therefore ln(xe^x) = lnx+1
f'=1/x  +1
f" = -1/(x^2)
 but i do not know the next step to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f'(x)=1+\frac  1x$ and $1-f''(x)=1+\frac  1 {x^{2}}$. On $(a,\infty)$ these functions have range $(1,1+\frac 1 a)$ and $(1,1+\frac 1 {a^{2}})$. The ranges are equal iff $a=a^{2}$ which gives $a=1$.